# how to change field variable/cell values in vti file with python script

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I have a `vti` file which contains certain geometry with hexagonal mesh. After a loading step a field variable name "concentration" changes and must be changed back zero. There is one possibility in paraview by hard way. Can any body share a way how to open, edit a field variable and overwrite a `vti` file with python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vtk` python module to do that.

1. read with `vtkXMLImageDataReader`
2. Get the array to modify `array = reader.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray("concentration")`
3. modify the array values by index: `array.InsertTuple(i, 0)`
4. write back with `vtkXMLImageDataWriter`

See the [read/write example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/ImageData/WriteReadVtkImageData/)

That is the native VTK solution. There is some other ways, as [using numpy](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/vtkNumPyIntegration.html#) to modify the data array, or do it in [ParaView python scripting](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/introduction.html#getting-started-with-pvpython)